# How to retrieve the output of for-loop (dictionary) from models to views?

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
   def my_dict(self):
         for i in range(n):
             …#some code
             context_a = {‘a’: a}
             return context_a
```

I need to take context into view like this:

```
from .models import ModelName

class ViewName
    model = ModelName
    template_name = ’template_name.html’

    def context_b(request):
        context_b = ModelName.objects.get(context_a=context_a) #here I want to get context_a as a dictionary and pass it to context_b for further operations. I know that my syntax here is not correct.
        return render(request, self.template_name, context_b)
```

If I do it, I get

```
Method Not Allowed: /

[18/Nov/2018 12:40:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

I would like to know how to do it correctly, and also which specific resource (documentation and/or article) should I read/learn to understand my problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try 
`ModelName.objects.post`. Since you are sending data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not subclassing proper class based view here.
The error you are getting is that, you are calling `get` method, but the View you have provided does not support that. For simplistic purpose, lets use [DetailsView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.DetailsView) which supports get request, so you can try like this:

```
class YourView(DetailsView):
  template_name = 'template_name.html'
  model = MyModel

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(YourView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context_a = self.object.my_dict()  # here you will get the dictionary from model in view
     # by the way, you can also access the your model object from context via context['object'] and in template via {{ object }}
     return context
```

And access dictionary of the template like this:

```
 {% for k, v in object.my_dict.items %}
      {{ k }} - {{ v }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Also the Url

```
#urls
path('/someview/<int:pk>/', YourView.as_view(), name="your_view"),
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, "_# unclear about what you are asking_" is unclear because it is unclear to myself.  How can I ask about context_a here: ModelName.objects.get(*** = ***)? It is subquestion about correct syntax.

Comment: @kokserek sorry I did not get that. Did you mean, you want to get `ModelName` object (via something you are not sure of) and based on that you want to get another `ModelName` object (from MyModel.objects.get)?

Comment: I just want to retrieve the *context_a* dictionary from models to views.

Comment: Sorry, can you kindly explain: in your code, what it *context*, *context_a* and *my_dict*? I am confused.

Comment: `context` is a dictionary which will be sent to the template. context_a is dictionary which is retrieved from `model_object.my_dict()` method. And my_dict is a model method.

Comment: Thank you so much! And could you also explain why it is important to use *DetailView* in my case?

Comment: `DetailView` is useful when you dealing with one object. Here we are accessing on object from `MyModel`, so its best to use it. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) regarding `DetailView`, it will help you how to implement it

Comment: Your help is very useful, thank you again. I will work on it more.